# understand Regular expression in a sed command

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I am learning Sed and I've been banging my head for an hour about to understand this command, here is the example from my book:

```
$ sed -n -e '/^[^|]*|[^|]*|56/w dpt_56' -e '/^[^|]*|[^|]*|89/w dpt_89' tel2.txt

$ cat dpt_56
Karama Josette|256 rue de la tempete|56100|Lorient|85.26.45.58
Zanouri Joel|45/48 boulevard du Gard|56100|Lorient|85/56/45/58
$ cat dpt_89
Joyeux Giselle|12. rue de la Source|89290|Vaux|45.26.28.47
```

Hers is what i understand:
- this command has the purpose to store in the dpt_56 file the lines of the poeple from the 56...district, ans the same for the 89 district in the dpt_89.

What I dont understand is the purpose or effect of the "|" and "^" caracters in the regex expression => What do `^[^|]*|[^|]*|56` means ? All i see is "choose every line that doesnt begin with zero or several times "|" OR that have several on no times "|"... but i get confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression `[^|]*|` means "any number of characters that aren't `|` followed by a `|`".
The reason `[^|]` is used instead of `.` is to ensure that the `.` wildcard doesn't greedily eat too much input.

It looks like the sed command itself is checking the 3rd field of a pipe delimited input.  If the value starts with `56` then it writes it to `dpt_56`, if the value starts with `89`, then it writes it to `dpt_89`.

Comment: Seems like `awk` would be more useful doesn't it?

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo - Absolutely.  Unless you really like regular expressions and extremely brief code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, now i finally get it! One more question: do i get the same result if i remove the first "^" ? like [^|]*|[^|]*|56

Comment: @badactadar - No/Maybe.  Outside of character classes (the stuff in between the `[]`) the `^` signifies the start of the string.  If you remove the `^` from the search pattern, you'll be looking for *any field* that starts with `56` that has at least two fields before it.  You might get the same results for your current data set, but don't count on it always being that way.

Comment: Just as an addendum to this, it is handy to notice that if you want to  use the alternation (or) symbol in sed you need to escape it with a backslash `\|` as outlined in [this question here](http://superuser.com/questions/111996/use-of-alternation-in-seds-regex)